# ng-model not being set for input color when style display is none

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

I have this html (below), for an input color type, I want to show the Font Awesome icons instead of the input, which works fine, the thing is that by setting the display of the input to none, the model is not being updated by the new color, this works fine if I remove the display setting. Any suggestions?

```
<label for="color{{id_form_group}}" class="fa-stack">
        <i class="fa fa-square-o fa-stack-2x"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-paint-brush fa-stack-1x" style="color:{{objeto.style.color}};"></i>
        <input id="color{{id_form_group}}" ng-model="objeto.style.color" type="color" style="display:none;">
</label>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will probably need to post the rest of your code, because I am able to get it to work fine with your code snippet:

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.objeto = {
    style: {
      color: ""
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
  <script>
    document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');
  </script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.5.x" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.11/angular.min.js" data-semver="1.5.11"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <p>Color: <span style="font-weight: bold; color: {{objeto.style.color}}">{{objeto.style.color}}</span></p>
  <form id="my-form">
    <label for="color{{id_form_group}}" class="fa-stack">
      <i class="fa fa-square-o fa-stack-2x"></i>
      <i class="fa fa-paint-brush fa-stack-1x" style="color:{{objeto.style.color}};"></i>
      <input id="color{{id_form_group}}" ng-model="objeto.style.color" type="color" style="display: none" />
    </label>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I don't know what is happening, in my laptop this snippet doesn't work, but in my desktop does!

Comment: @Typo check to see if you have any extensions / plugins installed on your laptop's browser.

Comment: I'm using chrome, on both computers they have the same extensions

Comment: @Typo on the laptop, does the debug console show any errors?

Answer (score 0):

Ok changing the css to `style="visibility:hidden;"` instead of `style="display:none;"` did the trick, I'm not sure why, if any one has a better answer or an explanation to why this happens, please post it and I'll mark your answer as correct.

Comment: The answer to that is here: [What is the difference between visibility:hidden and display:none?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133051/what-is-the-difference-between-visibilityhidden-and-displaynone). Key points: `visibility:hidden` : **The tag is rendered**, `display:none;` **it is not**

Comment: @lealceldeiro well...if it was for that answer display none should work..."...although you can still interact with it through the dom..." or do you mean that angular only works with rendered elements?

Comment: Yes, you're right. Maybe this is another thing to do with the AngularJS internals and worth of posting a question here on SO about it ;)

Answer (score 0):

You don't have   to use **`display:none`** with angularjs because it provides **`ng-hide`** and **`ng-show`** directives

This should do the trick,

```
<input id="color{{id_form_group}}" ng-model="objeto.style.color" type="color" ng-hide="true"">
```

Comment: Hi, setting it to visibility:hidden works too. Why would one work while the other doesnt?

Comment: i hope you got the answer in the below commnet

Comment: not really, that answer explains the difference between display none and visibility, not how angular works with elements according to their style.

Comment: why did you remove the answer? actually everything is explained here https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow

Comment: Sorry to rush in with the accepted answer, I've tried your solution and doesn't work. Maybe I forgot to mention that the html it's the template of another directive. Does that has something to do with it?

Comment: the chosen value is not being set to the model

Comment: plus, according to the documentation ng-hide is setting the display to none